# How can I execute a JS function without parenthesis?

Tags: javascript, function, execution

**What I want to do**

First of all, I would like to state that I am *not* looking for how to run a function by name (that's explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/359788)).

What I want to do is something like this:

```js
function myFunc(){
    // some code here
}

myFunc; // this should run the function

// I know it doesn't, but read below
```

**Why I want to do this**

There's a Google Easter egg, that if you type in [text adventure](https://www.google.com/search?q=text+adventure) into the search bar and open the console, you can play a text adventure game.

It asks,

> Would you like to play a game? (yes/no)

And if you type in `yes` (just the word yes), then it will start the real game.  I am trying to figure out how it does that (you didn't type in the `()` after it, and I already learned that [you can't see what the user types in the console](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54836184)), but can't figure out what they are doing.

My guess was that they are able to run a function when you type in `yes` (maybe a function called `yes`?), so that's why I asked this question to understand what they really are doing.

To prevent an XY question: what I *really* want to do is be able to run some code when the user types something ('yes' maybe) into the console.  It's just I think that they are running functions when that happens, so that's why I asked this specific question.

**Question**

So how is it possible to use the console as an input like Google's text adventure?

Comment: There are ways but it's just the wrong direction anyway. You should read the user input into a variable and then act on it - compare it to known values.

Comment: @CherryDT: OK, well maybe read it into variables - but how?  They entered something in the *console*, not a real `<input>`.

Comment: And I appreciate that you explained what you _really_ wanted to do, because your question is a perfect example for an XY question indeed! :)

Comment: Oooh I missed this part that it's just something in the console. Sorry about that. I cannot reproduce this easter egg though, for me no "do you want to play a game" prompt appears. Anyway, I guess you could create getters on the `window` object with your code. For example: `Object.defineProperty(window, 'yes', { get: () => console.log('OH YEAH') })`

Comment: `Object.defineProperty(window, 'yes', { get() { console.log("let's play") } })`

Comment: @CherryDT @ deceze: That's exactly what I wanted - although I'm not sure why my question was closed for something that has nothing to do with the console.  Thanks!

Comment: @CherryDT, `Object.defineProperty` is part of the first duplicate.

Comment: @NinaScholz: Oh, you have to scroll down the solutions to see the solution.  OK, that makes more sense.  Weird that I didn't see that question while searching.  Must have been that I used words that didn't match the one of that question.